# How to automatically install app on any watch android

Tags: android

I have developed an app for phone and smart watches. How can i sync app with android watch. I want to send both apps to client for testing but how can client install app on smartwatch they have. Is there any way that app on phone automatically sync smart watch app on his watch.I have read some articles but they show how to debug app using adb and other stuff.I guess client are not that technical i am new to watch apps so can anyone suggest me how it will be done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

"While you install your app directly unto a wearable during development, publishing and releasing an app for users is quite different. Your wearable app must be embedded in a handheld app, and it is automatically pushed onto wearables that are connected with the user’s handheld. Visit the Android Developer page on [packaging wearable apps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) for more information on properly packaging your wearable app."

Credits: [AndroidAuthority](http://www.androidauthority.com/develop-simple-android-wear-app-622043/)

Comment: Does different package name affects the result i am expecting? I have added my wear app as in my handheld app as mentioned in the doc and i have same application id but different package name and i even tried the release creating the release version of the app that creates the release APK of both handheld and wear app. So what i am expected to do now

Comment: Android Studio exports (into your project's root folder) a signed phone app that includes an embedded watch app.

This is what it should do create a single app .apk file but in my case it creates 2 Apk both for handheld and wear app

Comment: your package name is overridden by application id in Android studio when you generate apk. So, application id is main thing, you can set package name to anything

Comment: So what i am doing wrong any idea i got my app release APK but when i install it on my android phone which is connected to a watch it doesnt install watch app on watch